# Why does Multiplying a column stochastic matrix with a vector that sums to one result in vector that again has sum one

Tags: matrix, multiplication, stochastic

Suppose I have a `nxn` coulmn stochastic matrix. If  I multiply it by a vector of length `n` that has elements that sum to one I get a resultant vector of length `n` that again sums to one Why does this happen? What if I give the vector of lenght `n` sum =0.8 or some 1.2?

Edit:
What happens if one of the columns of the matrix dosent add up to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Consider matrix `B=4x4` and vector `A=4x1`. Now when we are calculating the output vector sum it can be broken as

```
a1*(b11+b21+b31+b41)+a2*(b12+b22+b32+b42)+a3*(b13+b23+b33+b43)+a4*(b14+b24+b34+b44)
```

Now since all columns sum to 1 since it's column stochastic the

```
sum=a1*1+a2*1+a3*1+a4*1=1
```

since the vector was 1. Now if one of the cols is not 1 we will have that column's contribution reduced for the jth entry of vector A. For eg. if

```
b13+b23+b33+b43=0.8
```

then

```
sum=a1*1+a2*1+a3*(0.8)+a4*1=a1*1+a2*1+a3*1+a4*1 -0.2*a3
```

So there is a leak of `-0.2a*3` from the original sum of 1